# Tar not preserving permissions on extract

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I'm backing up a users folder as root using tar

```
tar -czf /mnt/disk/cloud.tar.gz -C /home/cloud/ .
```

In /mnt/disk I do a test

```
tar ztvf cloud.tar.gz
```

and it shows

```
-rw-r--r-- cloud/cloud      14 2014-11-02 21:13 ./xebra.txt
```

however when I do an extract

```
tar zxpf cloud.tar.gz
```

the file then shows as

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 2014-11-02 21:13 xebra.txt
```

I've also tried the same command as the user cloud but still the same result.

Comment: Have you taken steps to confirm the problem really is with tar ? For example are you able to `chown` and `chmod` the file back to `-rw-r--r-- cloud/cloud` ?

Comment: Extracting the tar as cloud creating files owned by root would be a major GNU tar security issue. Either you confuse users when doing your experiments or the file system and location where you extract the files is part of the issue. What is mounted on /mnt/disk ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are extracting the archive on a file system that doesn't support file owners and groups and map all of them to root/root.